# Html.ActionLink and loading image display?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, loading, actionlink

I m showing a jquery ui dilog with link below. dialog opens 2 seconds later and I want to show a loding image until it opens. How can I do this?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ekle", "AddCustomer", "Customer", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "AddCustomerLink", data_dialog_title = "Yeni Müşteri" })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Ajax.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493106.aspx) instead and specify the [LoadingElementId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.loadingelementid.aspx) property.